# How to insert date into Oracle table from asp.net C# webform using an Oracle connection?

Tags: c#, asp.net, date

I have a table which I had created using Toad. This has a field called created which is going to store the date of creation, so I need to insert the date of creation from the code behind using C# and an Oracle Connection.

But I am unable to insert the date. While doing so it's throwing the exception **ORA-01843: not a valid month** and when I try to use the `to_date` function it's showing that `to_date` couldn't be found in the current context in Microsoft Visual Studio.

I used the following code:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Today;
.
.
.
cmd.CommandText = "insert into Employee (BADGE_ID, USER_ID, FNAME, LNAME,PLANNED_ALLOC, MANAGER, TEAM,CREATED,CREATED_BY,LAST_UPD,LAST_UPD_BY) values ( '" + bid + "', '" + uid + "', '" + fn + "', '" + ln + "', " + pa + ", '" + man + "', '" + team + "', '" + TO_DATE(dt.ToString(), "yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss") + "', '" + uid + "', '" + TO_DATE(dt.ToString(), 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss') + "', '" + uid + "')";
```

Comment: Don't concatenate your values like that.  Learn to use parameter binding instead: `cmd.Parameters.Add(...)`

Comment: Tidied spelling and grammar

Answer (score 0):

So, in this case, I would say let the database do the work. Use the GETDATE() function in your SQL statement and the server will format a full timestamp and stick it in there.

Answer (score 0):

The "TO_DATE" bit is part of the PL/SQL (you've got it as part of your c# command), so it should be part of the "CommandText" string.

So you want something like this:

```
    cmd.CommandText = "insert into Employee (BADGE_ID, USER_ID, FNAME, LNAME,PLANNED_ALLOC, MANAGER, TEAM,CREATED,CREATED_BY,LAST_UPD,LAST_UPD_BY) values ( '" + bid + "', '" + uid + "', '" + fn + "', '" + ln + "', " + pa + ", '" + man + "', '" + team + "', '" + TO_DATE(dt.ToString(), "yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss") + "', '" + uid + "',  TO_DATE(dt.ToString(), 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss') + ', '" + uid + "')";
```

[Notice I've removed the " (speech marks) which takes the TO_DATE out of the actual command string].

So it's got to be in the string that's "handed" to Oracle if you see what I mean.

Kind regards,
Mike